# getting XDMP-RIDXNOTFOUND error while running the SQL query from Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I recently got to work on setting up of MarkLogic server on my local Windows machine and trying the *SQL* to *MarkLogic* setup.

I was following the help document "https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/setup#id_51442" and tried creating views using curl.

Now when I run the query `Select * from employees` it gives me the following error:

> xdmp:sql("SELECT * from employees WHERE employees MATCH "Manager"...",
>   ()) -- SQL error: sqlite3-step() failed due to error 'VIEW-INVALID:
>   Illegal view specification: view specification is invalid:
>   XDMP-RIDXNOTFOUND: No int range index for EmployeeID
>   XDMP-RIDXNOTFOUND: No string range index for FirstName
>   XDMP-RIDXNOTFOUND: No string range index for LastName
>   http://marklogic.com/collation..."

It is asking me to create the range indexes, but I have no idea how to create this.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Regards,
Sendhil

Comment: Another resource you might find helpful: MarkLogic University's free courses. They are available instructor-led or [self-paced](https://mlu.marklogic.com/selfpaced/).

Comment: Do you need further specific assistance or does the answer given suffice?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to give yourself a bigger MarkLogic Primer before you're far enough along.

In this order:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql

When you get all the way into the intro (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro)
Look for the Bold section relating to **Columns and Range Indexes**

That will bring you here:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro#id_25570

And once you have your head around there, then look for the bold title called: **"Range Indexes and Lexicons"**

That brings you here:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index

By the time you have digested all of that, then you should have the knowledge you need.